# Sticky/snap scroll doesn't scroll back up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script that will allow for snap scrolling when you move down but I can't get it to allow the user to scroll back upwards.

```
var items = $(".item");
var animating = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    if (!animating) {
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
            items.each(function(key, value) {
                if ($(value).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()) {
                    animating = true;
                    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: $(value).offset().top + 'px' }, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 500);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }, 50));
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/77/

Comment: Please check updated fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/78/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
var body = $("html, body");
```

and

```
$(body).stop().animate( { scrollTop: $(value).offset().top)}, 1000,'swing');
```

**Chrome** reading `body` and srolling, **Firefox** need `html` to do it

[Check Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/79/)

Comment: How can I get it to have that same sticky behaviour when going back up though?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, was asleep. Is it possible to set an offset by percentage from the top of the viewport. I'd like it to not snap to the top of the viewport but rather, halfway down.